# Unable to update any software packages in VMWare Ubuntu

Tags: apt, updates, java, vmware

I want to understand why I am unable to install any packages. I am trying to install hadoop, but for that Ubuntu 14.04 & Java 7 or above are prerequisite and I cannot install them:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk Reading package lists... Error!    
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a shot:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

This will delete corrupted packages and reupdate.